# How to remove duplicates and sort in a subquery?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, greatest-n-per-group

I have records with a "title" column that I am splitting up by space and performing a full text search with each word. I am storing the result in a materialized view.

This works, but I get duplicate results for various words and I need to sort the results by their ranking. I can do one or the other - not both. How do I do both?

My query:

```sql
SELECT
    asset.id,
    (
        select
            jsonb_agg(resultsForWord)
        FROM
            UNNEST(
                string_to_array(TRIM(regexp_replace(asset.title, '[^a-zA-Z+]', ' ', 'g')), ' ')
            ) as word
            INNER JOIN LATERAL 
            (
                SELECT
                    searchresult.id,
                    searchresult.title,
                    ts_rank(ts, to_tsquery ('english', word)) rank
                FROM
                    assets searchresult
                WHERE
                    searchresult.id != asset.id AND
                    ts_rank(ts, to_tsquery ('english', word)) > 0.5
                LIMIT 5
            ) AS resultsForWord ON 1=1
     ) results
FROM
    assets asset
WHERE asset.id = 'abc'
GROUP BY asset.id;
```

To filter out duplicates I just did

```sql
jsonb_agg(DISTINCT resultsForWord)
```

To order by rank I just did

```sql
jsonb_agg(resultsForWord ORDER BY rank DESC)
```

When I do both I get:

> ```
> ERROR: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list
> ```

Example data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE assets (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT,
  ts tsvector 
   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title, '')), 'A')) STORED
)

INSERT INTO assets (id, title) VALUES ('a', 'Hello world!'),
  ('b', 'Hello sir'),
  ('c', 'I am above the world'),
  ('d', 'World hello')
```

Comment: Sample data (as text) and expected results would help, preferably as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements

Comment: What is this function `remove_by_string_length`? Also where are the duplicates coming from, is it from the `UNNEST` or from `INNER JOIN LATERAL`

Comment: Removed `remove_by_string_length`, added `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements for mock data. Duplicates are coming from the `INNER JOIN LATERAL` as the `UNNEST` just splits up the title by space

Comment: So what would your expected results be? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=369913a93afa95a64ccae46afe9dbf83 Seems you could get duplicates also from the `UNNEST` as the same word might appear twice in a value

Comment: @Charlieface "World hello" ("d") comes up twice. As for the `UNNEST` you are right but Ill cross that bridge when it comes up :D

Comment: Yes, but that's because it's finding two words with two rank values (in this case it just happens to be the same rank). What do you want to do? Average the rank? Take only one (which one)?

Comment: @Charlieface Take only 1 of the results with ID "d". They are _basically_ the same.

Comment: Is `assets.id`  actually `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` (like it probably should), and you just forgot to disclose that?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes - I wrote that from memory in a rush. Added (altho my question has been resolved)

Comment: I think there is more to resolve. Consider my added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you should flip the order of the join with `UNNEST` so that you only join a maximum of one row.

> Also you can remove the outer `GROUP BY`. It seems unnecessary

```
SELECT
    asset.id,
    (
        select
            jsonb_agg(results ORDER BY results.rank DESC)
        FROM (
            SELECT
                searchresult.id,
                searchresult.title,
                resultsForWord.rank
            FROM
                assets searchresult
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
            (
                SELECT ts_rank(ts, to_tsquery ('english', word)) rank
                FROM UNNEST(
                    string_to_array(TRIM(regexp_replace(asset.title, '[^a-zA-Z+]', ' ', 'g')), ' ')
                ) as word
                WHERE ts_rank(ts, to_tsquery ('english', word)) > 0.5
                ORDER BY rank DESC
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS resultsForWord
            WHERE
                searchresult.id != asset.id
            ORDER BY rank DESC
            LIMIT 5
        ) results
     ) results
FROM
    assets asset
WHERE asset.id = 'a';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cf1f7033b5364e60462572dc7a8a33e4)

Comment: Thanks that also speeds up the entire query immensely!

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, there can only be a single match in the outer query with `WHERE  a.id = 'abc'`, so the outer `GROUP BY` is definitely not needed (like Charlie already suggested).

"Duplicate results" like you report can be introduced in multiple spots:

1. Splitting up `title` produces duplicate words
2. Multiple (distinct) words can match the same row

Remove dupes early.

This looks mighty convoluted:

```
unnest(string_to_array(trim(regexp_replace(a.title, '[^a-zA-Z+]', ' ', 'g')), ' '))
```

Consider [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) instead:

```
regexp_split_to_table(a.title, '[^a-zA-Z]+')
```

(And I suggest you want `'[^a-zA-Z]+'` rather than `'[^a-zA-Z+]'`.)

The only shortcoming: may produce leading or trailing empty strings, but those can cheaply be eliminated with a `WHERE` clause.

So, I think, you rather want this query:

```
SELECT a.id
    , (  SELECT jsonb_agg(resultsforword)
         FROM  (
            SELECT *
            FROM  (
               SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.id)
                      r.id, r.title, r.rank
               FROM  (
                  SELECT word        -- remove duplicate words early
                  FROM   regexp_split_to_table(a.title, '[^a-zA-Z]+') word
                  WHERE  word <> ''  -- trim possible leading / trailing ''
                  ) w
               CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
                  SELECT s.id, s.title
                       , ts_rank(s.ts, to_tsquery('english', w.word)) AS rank
                  FROM   assets s
                  WHERE  s.id <> a.id
                  AND    ts_rank(s.ts, to_tsquery('english', w.word)) > 0.5
                  ORDER  BY rank DESC
                  LIMIT  5                  -- max. 5 best matches per word
                  ) r
               ORDER  BY r.id, r.rank DESC  -- take best rank for each dupe result
               ) r
            ORDER  BY r.rank DESC, r.id     -- best rank overall, id as tiebreaker
            LIMIT  5                        -- max 5 overall 
            ) resultsforword
     ) AS results
FROM   assets a
WHERE  a.id = 'e';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=58bad2c0e1480775a804fa5ba88478de)*

This gets the 5 best matches for any of the words in the selected title. Looks more complex now, but operating with due diligence we have to:

1. Extract words from selected `title`.
2. Get the best (max.) 5 matches per word. This can match to the same row multiple times (with different rank).
3. Get best rank for each resulting row - in case the same row matched on multiple words.
4. Get 5 rows with best rank.

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)